# Cannot download file in SP Online using Get-PnpFile

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Hi why do I receive a file not found error when downloading a file from SharePoint Online using **Get-PnpFile** in PowerShell even though I can get its details on my first line of code below:

[image]

[image]

I just simply followed the code here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/powershell/GetPnPFile.md

I am a site collection admin to the site but still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you add `-AsFile` in the end? Does `c:\temp` contain your file? Do you have write permissions to this folder?

Comment: Hi I just followed the code on the link from Github. I tried to remove -AsFile see my updated post it prompts me to supply new value. For C:\ temp is my local drive and have admin privileges.

Comment: Try `-AsFile $false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use decoded Url path and for the safety purpose, please include the path under quotes. I have tried this command and it worked like a charm

```
Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/PSD-Dev/Bulk Docs Library/Folder Level 1/Folders With Files/SubFolderFile1/sample File No- 2.txt" -Path D:\DvG -Filename "sample File No- 2.txt" -AsFile
```

**PS:** I am using pnp powershell version *'2.26.1805.1'*
Run this command to update to latest pnp-powershell version

```
install-module sharepointpnppowershellonline -Force
```

Comment: I'm using the same version. I saw some post that this only work if you are a tenant admin.

Comment: In this case I am only a site coll admin.. not a tenant admin

Comment: Also, you can check if you have set up the set-executionpolicy remotesigned ..for ur machine

Comment: I got this error: Get-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot bind parameter 'Scope'.

Comment: Follow this: for setting the execution policy https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6   . Let me know if any issue?

Comment: Maybe i have missing Pnp cmdlets that needs to be installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78523/discussion-between-bizapps-and-dvg).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. It worked if I used a " " instead of the %20 in the url.

After debugging the code I found that the issue was with the 
`GetFileByServerRelativePath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl(serverRelativeUrl)` call that `Get-PnpFile` uses when downloading the file.  I then stumbled on this:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api.

`Get-PnpFile` doesn't treat the URL in this way if fetching the file object so confusingly, the %20 is fine in the URL for that type of call.